# Can I set batch size to 1

Tags: train

I am trying to train a [T5](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v2.9.1/model_doc/t5.html) (t5_large) transformer model on some data. Since it's out of `cuda` memory, I was forced to set `batch_size` to 1 so that I can run the model on my computer.

Now, my question is what other consideration I must take into account. Should I check the model convergence? if yes how? Then, should I increase the epochs? It's currently 1 epoch.

Comment: If your dataset is large, why would the batch size affect the convergence?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Yes, the dataset is large. I don't know how or when or why it affects or not, that's actually my question.